# Thurston measure under finite covers

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let $S= S_{g,n}$ be a finite type orientable surface of genus $g$ and $n$ punctures and let $\mathcal{ML}(S)$ denote the corresponding space of measured laminations. The Thurston measure, $\mu^{Th},$ is a mapping class group invariant and locally finite Borel measure on $\mathcal{ML}(S)$ which is obtained as a weak-$\star$ limit of (appropriately weighted and rescaled) sums of Dirac measures supported on the set of integral multi-curves.

The Thurston measure arises in Mirzakhani's curve counting framework. Concretely, given a hyperbolic metric $\rho$ on $S_{g,n}$, let $B_{\rho} \subset \mathcal{ML}(S)$ denote the set of measured laminations with $\rho$-length at most $1$. Then $\mu^{Th}(B_{\rho})$ controls the top coefficient of the polynomial that counts multi-curves up to a certain $\rho$-length and living in a given mapping class group orbit.

**Question:** Fix a hyperbolic metric $\rho$ on $S$ and a finite (not necessarily regular) cover $p: Y \rightarrow S$. Let $\rho_{p}$ denote the hyperbolic metric on $Y$ obtained by pulling $\rho$ back to $Y$ via $p$. Is there a straightforward relationship between $\mu^{Th}(B_{\rho_{p}})$ and $\mu^{Th}(B_{\rho})$? For example, is the ratio
$$    \frac{\mu^{Th}(B_{\rho})}{\mu^{Th}(B_{\rho_{p}})}  $$
uniformly bounded away from $0$ and $\infty$? Does it equal a fixed value, independent of $\rho$? If so, can it be easily related to the degree of the cover $Y \rightarrow S$?

It seems hard to approach the above by thinking about counting curves on $Y$ versus $S$, because "most" simple closed curves on $Y$ project to non-simple curves on $S$. But, maybe the generalizations of curve counting for non-simple curves due to Mirzakhani (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.03342.pdf) or Erlandsson-Souto (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.05091.pdf) could be useful. Of course, both apply to counting curves in a fixed mapping class group orbit, so it's not clear (to me) how to apply these results either since multi-curves on $Y$ can project to curves on $S$ with arbitrarily large self intersection.

Thanks for reading! I appreciate any ideas or reading suggestions.